# How to deserialize an array of aliases into an enum with serde

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to deserialize a JSON structure which has an array of strings, which are basically aliases to the enum I want to retrieve.

The JSON structure is:

```json
{
    "some_field": "abc",
    "species": ["homosapiens", "hs", "human"]
}
```

And my target structure is:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Species {
    #[serde(alias = "homosapiens", alias = "hs")]
    HomoSapiens,
    #[serde(alias = "musmusculus", alias = "mouse")]
    MusMusculus
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    species: Species,
}
```

My goal is, that in deserializing, it sees that the "species" field in the JSON contains at least one matching alias. So for example, if the JSON data has "hs" in the "species" array, it is seen as the enum variant "HomoSapiens", and if it were "mouse" it would be the enum variant "MusMusculus".

I tried to add a custom deserialization method but I can not find out how to check if one of the string values matches any of the aliases.

```rust
fn deserialize_species<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Species, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let species_names: Vec<String> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    // TODO: Check if any of these strings are an alias

    Err(D::Error::custom("Could not deserialize species"))
}
```

**Note:** I did not forget to add the #[serde(deserialize_with)] tag.

Is there a method on the "Species" enum I can call that tries to serialize it from one of these strings which keeps the aliases in mind? I can not find it in the documentation but I might have looked over it.

Comment: Can an array contain `["hs" , "mouse"]`?

Comment: No it can not contain aliases from another variant

Comment: wait the type is inside an array ? just throw away this api design

Comment: sorry I do not understand your comment?

Comment: well sorry I don't understand your question :p

Comment: @Stargateur The variant (or an alias to it) is inside the array...
I think the best option would be to implement Deserialize for `MyStruct` and then setting the variant explicitely using a `match`.

Comment: @frankenapps Yes I was afraid of that, as the variants could grow to a larger list. Although it would not be a huge list so it might be worth the effort compared to trying to do this with serde

Comment: At some point in your code you will have to write down these aliases nevertheless, so I think it really shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 1):

This deserializes every string in the vector and returns the first species, which can be deserialized.

```rust
fn deserialize_species<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Species, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let species_names: Vec<String> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    for sn in species_names {
        if let Ok(species) = serde_plain::from_str(&sn) {
            return Ok(species);
        }
    }

    Err(D::Error::custom("Could not deserialize species"))
}
```

> Is there a method on the "Species" enum I can call that tries to serialize it from one of these strings which keeps the aliases in mind?

The method is the `deserialize` method. serde does not offer any way to inspect the generated code. But you can use a simple deserializer like `serde_plain` to use it.